# What type of Authentication System does Django use out of the box?

Tags: django

What type of Authentication System does Django use out of the box?

Looks to me like Session Based Authentication?

Comment: yes, you are correct. Django uses session-based authentication by default.

Answer (score 1):

As per [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests):

> ### Authentication in Web requests
>
> Django uses [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/) and middleware to hook the authentication system into request objects.
>
> These provide a [request.user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user) attribute on every request which represents the current user. If the current user has not logged in, this attribute will be set to an instance of [AnonymousUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser), otherwise it will be an instance of [User](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User).
>
> You can tell them apart with [is_authenticated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated), like so:
>
> ```
> if request.user.is_authenticated:
>     # Do something for authenticated users.
>     ...
> else:
>     # Do something for anonymous users.
>     ...
> ```